# Junit Respository test cases

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, java-17

**This is my repository class**

```
@Repository
public interface ExamResultRepository
    extends JpaRepository<ExamResult, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ExamResult> {


  @Query(
      value =
          """
                  SELECT
                    d."name" AS domain,
                    COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalPass,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalFail,
                    (SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS passPercentage,
                    (SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS failPercentage
                  FROM
                    exam_result er
                  JOIN public.exam e ON
                    er.exam_id = e.id
                  JOIN domain d ON
                    e.domain_id = d.id
                  GROUP BY
                    d.name;
                 """,
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<DomainWiseSuccessRatio> getDomainWiseSuccessRatio();
}
```

**DomainWiseSuccessRatio is interface because i am using projection**

```
public interface DomainWiseSuccessRatio {

  String getDomain();

  int getTotalCount();

  int getTotalPass();

  int getTotalFail();

  double getPassPercentage();

  double getFailPercentage();
}
```

**I am using mokito with JUnit5**

**I am writing test cases for repository method**

```
@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(TestConstant.TEST_PROFILE)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class ExamResultRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired ExamResultRepository examResultRepository;

  @Autowired ExamRepository examRepository;

  @Autowired DomainRepository domainRepository;

  @Autowired QuestionRepository questionRepository;

  private List<Question> questionList;
  private Domain domain;
  private Topic topic;
  private Exam exam;
  private ExamResult examResult;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    List<QuestionMcq> questionMcq = QuestionMcqTestData.createMcq();
    questionList = QuestionTestData.createQuestionsList(domain, topic, questionMcq);
    domain = DomainTestData.createDomain();
    topic = TopicTestData.createTopic(domain);
    exam = ExamTestData.createExamData(domain);
    examResult = ExamResultTestData.createExamResultData(exam);
  }
    void getDomainWiseSuccessRatio() {

      // Create and persist domains
      Domain domain1 = new Domain();
      domain1.setName("Math");
      domainRepository.save(domain1);

      Domain domain2 = new Domain();
      domain2.setName("Science");
      domainRepository.save(domain2);

      // Create and persist exams associated with domains
      Exam exam1 = new Exam();
      exam1.setDomain(domain1);
      examRepository.save(exam1);

      Exam exam2 = new Exam();
      exam2.setDomain(domain2);
      examRepository.save(exam2);

      // Create and persist exam results associated with exams
      ExamResult result1 = new ExamResult();
      result1.setPassed(true);
      result1.setExam(exam1);
      examResultRepository.save(result1);

      ExamResult result2 = new ExamResult();
      result2.setPassed(false);
      result2.setExam(exam2);
      examResultRepository.save(result2);

      // Call the method to be tested
      List<DomainWiseSuccessRatio> result = examResultRepository.getDomainWiseSuccessRatio();

      // Assertions
      assertNotNull(result);
      assertEquals(2, result.size());

      // Test specific values for the first item (Math)
      assertEquals("Math", result.get(0).getDomain());
      assertEquals(1, result.get(0).getTotalCount());
      assertEquals(1, result.get(0).getTotalPass());
      assertEquals(0, result.get(0).getTotalFail());
      assertEquals(100.0, result.get(0).getPassPercentage());
      assertEquals(0.0, result.get(0).getFailPercentage());

      // Test specific values for the second item (Science)
      assertEquals("Science", result.get(1).getDomain());
      assertEquals(1, result.get(1).getTotalCount());
      assertEquals(0, result.get(1).getTotalPass());
      assertEquals(1, result.get(1).getTotalFail());
      assertEquals(0.0, result.get(1).getPassPercentage());
      assertEquals(100.0, result.get(1).getFailPercentage());

    }
}
```

**When i executed my test cases facing this error**

```
could not prepare statement; SQL [ SELECT
   d."name" AS domain,
   COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
   SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalPass,
   SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalFail,
   (SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS passPercentage,
   (SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS failPercentage
 FROM
   exam_result er
 JOIN public.exam e ON
   er.exam_id = e.id
 JOIN domain d ON
   e.domain_id = d.id
 GROUP BY
   d.name;
]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [ SELECT
   d."name" AS domain,
   COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
   SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalPass,
   SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalFail,
   (SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS passPercentage,
   (SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS failPercentage
 FROM
   exam_result er
 JOIN public.exam e ON
   er.exam_id = e.id
 JOIN domain d ON
   e.domain_id = d.id
 GROUP BY
   d.name;
]
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:232)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy135.getDomainWiseSuccessRatio(Unknown Source)
    at app//com.testiqo.exam.engine.repository.ExamResultRepositoryTest.getDomainWiseSuccessRatio(ExamResultRepositoryTest.java:194)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.7/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at app//org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:64)
    at app//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at app//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at app//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at app//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:75)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.lambda$list$0(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:100)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:171)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getMetaData(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:33)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.getColumnCount(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:49)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.results.ResultSetMappingImpl.resolve(ResultSetMappingImpl.java:187)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.resolveJdbcValuesSource(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:559)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:350)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91)
    at app//org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.performList(NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:105)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:602)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363)
    at app//org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "public" not found; SQL statement:
 SELECT
   d."name" AS domain,
   COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
   SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalPass,
   SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalFail,
   (SUM(CASE WHEN er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS passPercentage,
   (SUM(CASE WHEN NOT er.is_pass THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0) / COUNT(*) AS failPercentage
 FROM
   exam_result er
 JOIN public.exam e ON
   er.exam_id = e.id
 JOIN domain d ON
   e.domain_id = d.id
 GROUP BY
   d.name;
 [90079-214]
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632)
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at app//org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1833)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2334)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2369)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2772)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2878)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2762)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2633)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2612)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2605)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2598)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2567)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
    at app//org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
    at app//org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
    at app//org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
    at app//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at app//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
    at app//org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327)
    at app//com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at app//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90)
    at app//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 124 more
```

## How solve tis error

**And i don't need to use mokito stubing for repository test cases.And  i am using H2 in-memory database for test cases**

Comment: `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "public" not found` - is there a reason why you access the table `exam` with a specific schema and the others without schema? Try to replace `JOIN public.exam` with `JOIN exam`.